# Remove rows corresponding to certain levels in a column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, merge

My [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/nationalparkservice/park-biodiversity?select=species.csv) is merged from 2 huge datasets and then NA-removed. It is now in shape (2707,18).

I have done

```
parks= pd.read_csv('parks.csv')
species= pd.read_csv('species.csv')
data= pd.merge(parks, species, on='Park Name')
variables= list(data.columns)[:-1]
print(parks.columns)
print('')
print(species.columns)
print('')
print(variables)
data= data.loc[:, variables]
data= data.dropna()
print(data.shape)

# The output:
Index(['Park Code', 'Park Name', 'State', 'Acres', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'], dtype='object')

Index(['Species ID', 'Park Name', 'Category', 'Order', 'Family',
       'Scientific Name', 'Common Names', 'Record Status', 'Occurrence',
       'Nativeness', 'Abundance', 'Seasonality', 'Conservation Status',
       'Unnamed: 13'],
      dtype='object')

['Park Code', 'Park Name', 'State', 'Acres', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Species ID', 'Category', 'Order', 'Family', 'Scientific Name', 'Common Names', 'Record Status', 'Occurrence', 'Nativeness', 'Abundance', 'Seasonality', 'Conservation Status']
(2707, 18)
```

I have looked up the levels of one categorical variable in the data and noticed there are some irrelevant levels. These levels (seemingly belonging to other variables) came from the data 'species'.

```
print(data.groupby('Record Status').size())
# Output:

Record Status
 American Crow             1
 Bushtit                   1
 Cabezon                   1
 Catbird                   1
 Cocodrilo De Tumbes       1
 Common Poorwill           1
 Northern Goshawk          1
 Northern Pintail          1
 Pigeon Hawk               1
 Robin                     1
 Short-Tailed Weasel       1
 Speckled Trout            1
 Wapiti                    1
 White-Footed Mouse        1
Approved                2668
In Review                 25
```

I have tried to keep the rows where the column 'Record Status' takes values only in ['Approved','In Review'] by

```
data= data[(data.loc[:,'Record Status']=='Approved') & (data.loc[:,'Record Status']=='In Review')]
```

But that removes all the rows in data, i.e. data.shape is now (0,18).

Otherwise, I have tried pd.isin

```
data= data[data.loc[:,'Record Status'].isin(['Approved', 'In Review'])]
print(data.groupby('Record Status').size())

# Output:
Record Status
Approved    2668
dtype: int64
```

This time only one level is kept, while observations of level 'In Review' are removed. What can I do to remove all these levels 'by mistake' from my data frame? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [pandas.Series.str.strip()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove heading and tailing whitespace in column `Record Status` and use [pandas.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to filter column

```py
data['Record Status'] = data['Record Status'].str.strip()
data_ = data[data['Record Status'].isin(['Approved', 'In Review'])]
```